# How to import custom option values with magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I would like to create a customizable options with magmi. For example I have a menu drop-down or choose a texture type. I read that should add a custom_option column, but what do I put in this column?

Comment: I also find the explanation here quite unclear http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options